# NodeJs: Trigger API's which are in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJs, apologies if this query is basic one.

Implemented the API's like below and everything working fine

**UserServices.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const createUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    email: String,
    contactNumber: String,
    password: String
});

export default mongoose.model("users", createUserSchema);
```

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Cors from "cors";

import GlobalVars from "./utils/GlobalVars";
import createUserSchema from "./apis/services/UserServices";

// App Config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

// DB Config (Connecting DB)
mongoose.connect(GlobalVars.MONGO_DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// API Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello World"));

app.post("/create_user", (req, res) => {
    const userData = req.body;
    console.log("userData " + JSON.stringify(userData));

    createUserSchema.create(userData, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data);
        }
    });
});


app.get("/users_list", (req, res) => {
    createUserSchema.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});

// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on host: ${port}`));
```

but i don't want to mention `get` and `post` calls in the `server.js`, want to make `server.js` **as clean as possible**. So, would like to mention `get` and `post` calls in `UserServices.js`. For this, followed below structure but it's not working

**UserServices.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";


const app = express();

const createUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    email: String,
    contactNumber: String,
    password: String
});

mongoose.model("users", createUserSchema);

const createUser = () => {
    app.post("/create_user", (req, res) => {
        const userData = req.body;
        console.log("userData " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    
        createUserSchema.create(userData, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(201).send(data);
            }
        });
    });
};


const getUsersList = () => {
    app.get("/users_list", (req, res) => {
        createUserSchema.find((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

export { createUser, getUsersList };
```

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Cors from "cors";

import GlobalVars from "./utils/GlobalVars";
import { createUser, getUsersList } from "./apis/services/UserServices";

// App Config
const app = express();
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

// DB Config (Connecting DB)
mongoose.connect(GlobalVars.MONGO_DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// API Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello World"));

createUser();

getUsersList();

// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on host: ${port}`));
```

My query is, how to mention API's globally or how to trigger API's which are written in another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating two different apps here (with two calls to `express()`). Instead, you can just pass your `app` reference defined in server.js to the `createUser` and `getUsersList` functions:

```js
// server.js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Cors from "cors";

import GlobalVars from "./utils/GlobalVars";
import { createUser, getUsersList } from "./apis/services/UserServices";

// App Config
const app = express();
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

// DB Config (Connecting DB)
mongoose.connect(GlobalVars.MONGO_DB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// API Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello World"));

createUser(app);

getUsersList(app);

// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on host: ${port}`));
```

Then, get rid of `const app = express();` in UserServices.js and have the `createUser` and `getUserList` functions accept `app` as a parameter:

```js
// UserServices.js

import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    email: String,
    contactNumber: String,
    password: String
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);

const createUser = app => {
    app.post("/create_user", (req, res) => {
        const userData = req.body;
        console.log("userData " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    
        userModel.create(userData, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(201).send(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

const getUsersList = app => {
    app.get("/users_list", (req, res) => {
        userModel.find({/*query here if any*/}, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

export { createUser, getUsersList };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, getting this error `TypeError: createUserSchema.find is not a function`

Comment: You don't execute queries on schemas, but on models. See my edits above for hints as to how to change your code (but the question of how to use Mongoose probably should not be dealt with under the question you posted as it is separate from how to define your handlers from another file, which has been addressed).